# chrome extension and Facebook login problems

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome, iframe

I try to write a chrome extension which is triggered by visting a certain website. So far this works already. My extension users are from my web game where they login with their facebook account. For identifying the extension users with their game account I need to know their fb app scoped user id from my game.

So far I learned my background script is not able to use the facebook sdk for login because window.fbAsyncInit isn't called inside.  I looked around for solutions and I found this page: http://brianmayer.com/2012/12/building-a-chrome-extension-that-connects-to-a-facebook-app/

He opens an invisible tab that contains an iframe. Inside of the iframe he calles the facebook login sdk from the webserver and then sends the user data with windows.postmessage to the parent. That sounds like the perfect solution for my problem. There is only one line that I don't understand what I have to add there:

```
parent.postMessage({connectStatus:"" + response.status + "", userID:"" + uid + "", accessToken:"" + at + ""}, "https://www.<PARENT_PAGE_DOMAIN>"); //This MUST match the root domain where the iFrame will be inserted, or the message won't get passed
```

What do I have to add in the field PARENT_PAGE_DOMAIN? I used the root domain of the page which is in the content_scripts/maches in the manifest file and I used the domain where the iframe page is hosted but I never receive the message in my background script

Comment: The comment says it needs to be domain name of the page that you inserted the iframe into ...

Comment: Yes I have read that but like I wrote I don't know how domain url is when I create dynamic a  html which includes an iframe inside of a background script? I mean only the file inside the iframe has a real http addess. The parent of that is the background script from the extension. So where can I see which url that background file has?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try use this ? 
[enter link description here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity#method-launchWebAuthFlow)

First of all you need to get redirect url
[image: get redirect url]
Here is my code:

```
chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({
    url: AUTH_URL,
    interactive: true
  }, function(redirectURL) {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
      alert(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
    }
    if(redirectURL){
      var q = redirectURL.substr(redirectURL.indexOf('#')+1);
      var parts = q.split('&');
      for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        var kv = parts[i].split('=');
        if (kv[0] == 'access_token') {
          var token = kv[1];
          console.log(token)
          // do something...
        }
      }
    }
  });
```